# EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\"C:'

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, ssh-keys, vscode-remote

I am attempting to update my Remote SSH config file, but i'm getting this error when i press 'F1' and click 'Remote-SSH: Open Configuration File'.

The extention is configured with this absolute path:

"C:\Users\me\.ssh\config"

Noticing the error is adding an extra quote in the directory path.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bsjY.png)